# Find the minimum and maximum of $P=x^2+y^2$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x^2-y^2+1)^2+4x^2y^2-x^2-y^2=0$. Find minimize and maximize of $$P=x^2+y^2$$

---

I just have $$(x^2-y^2+1)^2+4x^2y^2-x^2-y^2=0$$

Or $$4y^2=\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2+\left(x^2+y^2\right)+1$$

Or $$4y^2-(P^2+P+1)=0 (\text{*})$$

The equation (*) has root only $0^2-4\cdot 4\cdot \left(P^2+P+1\right)\ge 0$ then we found max and min of $P$ but it's wrong. Otherhand the equation occurs when $x\ne y $ so i cant use any inequalities. Help me

Comment: Well, $P^2+P+1=4y^2\leq 4(x^2+y^2)=4P$ so $$P^2-3P+1\leq0.$$  Hence, $$\left(P-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left( P -\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\leq 0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your work: I got the maximum as $$\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{5})^2$$ and this will attained for $$x=0,y=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$$
The minimum is given by $$\frac{1}{4}(-1+\sqrt{5})$$ and will get for
$$x=0,y=\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{5})$$